# Single login for multiple clients in same realm?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I watched the recent Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duawSV69LDI) intro to Keycloak and have been following along with the examples used here: https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-containers-demo

I have it all working fine, and I am trying to test what this might look like with more applications. So I have added an additional Jenkins app to the mix and configured it to use the OIDC plugin for authentication. Was easy and works great.  So now I have one realm with two clients, jenkins and the js-console.  I am seeing some unexpected behaviors and wondering if I am doing something wrong or just have a fundamental misunderstanding about what Keycloak can provide.

1. I am not getting SSO. If I access the js-console app and login and then open the URL for Jenkins I am redirected to Keycloak and have to login again. I was expecting SSO to happen here. Doesn't Keycloak set a cookie or something so that I would be logged in to the second app? Thinking out loud .. could the fact that I am not using SSL be the issue? Maybe the cookie is marked as secure?
2. I went ahead and added Github login like in the demo. From what I can tell this will only work with one client. Both my clients get the same login screen so both have the login with Github option available, but the redirect URL's can only be configured for one of the clients. Is there a solution for this so that you could have many clients sharing the same realm and allow login via social login?

I would like to eventually test a SAML provider like Okta and am wondering if I will run into the same problem with that as I did with Github?

Comment: I setup SSL in my docker-compose using an nginx proxy. With everything behind SSL it seems like the SSO works.  So I am guessing my theory about the cookie might be why this was not working. Would be great to have confirmation as well as feedback on the social login/SAML question.